# Importing available module into PowerShell v2.0 results in error

Tags: ssh, windows-7, powershell, import

I'm trying to import a PowerShell module to do some SSH work. I've unlocked all of the files I'm trying to import in the module. The module itself is located in a directory where modules are to be located in order to be found.

```
PS C:\Users\AM034402> Get-Module -ListAvailable

ModuleType Name                      ExportedCommands
---------- ----                      ----------------
Manifest   SSH-Sessions              {}
Manifest   AppLocker                 {}
Manifest   BitsTransfer              {}
Manifest   PSDiagnostics             {}
Manifest   TroubleshootingPack       {}


PS C:\Users\AM034402> Import-Module SSH-Sessions
Import-Module : The specified module 'SSH-Sessions' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module
 directory.
At line:1 char:14
+ Import-Module <<<<  SSH-Sessions
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (SSH-Sessions:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
```

As you can see, PowerShell finds the module in the Available list, but trying to export it gets an error. I retrieved the file from [this link](http://www.powershelladmin.com/w/images/6/60/SSH-Sessions.zip) on [this wiki page](http://www.powershelladmin.com/wiki/SSH_from_PowerShell_using_the_SSH.NET_library). Any clues as to what is up here?

Comment: Can you show us what the directory structure of the module looks like on the filesystem?

Comment: You downloaded the version designed for PS v2.0 right?  Since you have tagged this Windows 7, I am curious why you haven't upgraded to WMF4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue occurs if the package is not available or resides in the wrong directory

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Import-Module SSH-Sessions
Import-Module : The specified module 'SSH-Sessions' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any
module directory.
At line:1 char:1
+ Import-Module SSH-Sessions
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (SSH-Sessions:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
```

After reading [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6412921/powershell-import-module-doesnt-find-modules) and trying to solve the issue the following answer has been formulated:

Download [the SSH-Sessions.zip](http://www.powershelladmin.com/w/images/6/60/SSH-Sessions.zip) by clicking the download link on [this webpage](http://www.powershelladmin.com/wiki/SSH_from_PowerShell_using_the_SSH.NET_library).

Extract the package to `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules`

Verify whether the package is available in PowerShell by issuing the following:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32>  Get-Module -ListAvailable

    Directory: C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules

ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------

Script     1.4        SSH-Sessions                        {ConvertFrom-SecureToPlain,
Manifest   1.0.0.0    StartScreen                         {Export-StartLayout, Import-
Manifest   2.0.0.0    Storage                             {Add-InitiatorIdToMaskingSet
```

If the module is available, it is possible to import it by executing `Import-Module SSH-Sessions`.

Comment: This worked. I also found that you should extract the files to a folder outside of your Modules folder, unblock the folder that contains the module, then copy it over.